# HHH000099: an assertion failure occurred (this may indicate a bug in Hibernate, but is more likely due to unsafe use of the session)

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I have the following error and I am trying to figure out the reason. As far as I know, this is not caused by Hibernate but the way I manage/use the method calls (Transient entity instance, save, detach and then merge). I do not get why this problem happens. I would really appreciate your explanation.

Error:
HHH000099: an assertion failure occurred (this may indicate a bug in Hibernate, but is more likely due to unsafe use of the session): org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: possible non-threadsafe access to session

FYI:
Java Version: 1.8
Hibernate version: https://hibernate.org/orm/releases/5.5/

```
package lk.mysite.demo.orm;

import lk.mysite.demo.orm.entity.Customer;
import lk.mysite.demo.orm.util.HibernateUtil;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

public class ContextDemo16 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (SessionFactory sf = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
             Session session = sf.openSession();) {
            session.beginTransaction();

            Customer customer = new Customer(5, "John", "New York");
            session.save(customer);
            session.detach(customer);
            session.merge(customer);
            // prompt an error

            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```